# Mongoose populate() returns array of objects instead of single object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, orm, mongoose

I have a collection which has a attribute which references an objectId of another collection.

```
placeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    category: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' }],
    facilities: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'facilities' }],
});
```

the `category` ref is an objectId of the `categories` collection. The `facilities` ref is an array of objectId's of the `facilities` collection.

When I populate the attributes, `facilities` becomes and array of the `facilities` objecrts but `category` also becomes an array of one single `category`.

```
Place.find(query).populate('category').populate('facilities').limit(limit).skip(offset).exec(function(err, data){
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.json(data);
});
```

Here's an example of the above query:

```
{
    "_id": "52ff59be70e8f0dfc8358cb4",
    "address": {
        "address_1": "Chambers Street",
        "city": "Edinburgh",
        "postcode": "EH1 1JF"
    },
    "description": "The National Museum of Scotland brings together our rich Scottish heritage with exciting international collections.",
    "loc": {
        "lon": -3.188384,
        "lat": 55.94772
    },
    "name": "National Museum of Scotland",
    "facilities": [
        {
            "_id": "53012d5b65b5e9a35efbb214",
            "name": "Facility One"
        },
        {
            "_id": "53012d6965b5e9a35efbb215",
            "name": "Facility Two"
        }
    ],
    "category": [
        {
            "_id": "52ffbf33605d0c81f36d98e0",
            "name": "Museums",
            "slug": "museums"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the document as it is in Mongo:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ff59be70e8f0dfc8358cb4"),
    "address" : {
        "address_1" : "Chambers Street",
        "city" : "Edinburgh",
        "postcode" : "EH1 1JF"
    },
    "category" : ObjectId("52ffbf33605d0c81f36d98e0"),
    "description" : "The National Museum of Scotland brings together our rich Scottish heritage with exciting international collections.",
    "facilities" : [
        ObjectId("53012d5b65b5e9a35efbb214"),
        ObjectId("53012d6965b5e9a35efbb215")
    ],
    "loc" : {
        "lon" : -3.188384,
        "lat" : 55.94772
    },
    "name" : "National Museum of Scotland"
}
```

How do I populate my single `category` ref instead of an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes sense since you in the schema definition have declared the category field to be an array:

```
category: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' }]
```

The following should work to not put it in an array (remove the `[]`):

```
category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' }
```

That is assuming that you indeed want only one category.

Comment: I just thought it required an array I did't actually think that determined the result. Doh! Thanks Andreas!